# Rename outputs from QGIS processing saga algorithms

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

I have a processing script which chains together several saga processing tools like this:

```
outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_3=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', inputvx,[inputvy],'(atan2(a,b)) * (180/pi())',True,7,None)
outputs_SAGAGRIDVALUESTOPOINTS_1=processing.runalg('saga:gridvaluestopoints', [outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_3['RESULT'],PolygonExtent,None,True,0,OutputName)
```

The calculator process defaults to calling the raster calculator output'RESULT', which means it ends up using the same interim file when you run a batch process - they are all called result regardless of the inputs.

How do I change the name of the calculation result to be something other than 'result'?

Here's the python console for the calculator tool - I assume I can alter both 'Result:' and 'Name:' but it won't seem to allow me to add any other parameters into the tool.

```
        Grid system: 10; 2601x 1500y; 383472.948554x 557408.826780y
        Grids: 1 object (Tyne10mBaselineUpdated02MainFlood0100Vx)
        Grids from different Systems: 1 object (Tyne10mBaselineUpdated02MainFlood0100Vy)
        Result: Result
        Formula: (atan2(a,b)) * (180/pi())
        Name: Calculation
        Take Formula: no
        Use NoData: yes
        Data Type: 4 byte floating point number
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround could be to add the following line at the end of your script which will load the output file with the filename you gave it:

```
iface.addVectorLayer(OutputName, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(OutputName))[0], "ogr")
```

---

So your script could look like:

```
outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_3=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', inputvx,[inputvy],'(atan2(a,b)) * (180/pi())',True,7,None)
outputs_SAGAGRIDVALUESTOPOINTS_1=processing.runalg('saga:gridvaluestopoints', outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_3['RESULT'],PolygonExtent,None,True,0,OutputName)

iface.addVectorLayer(OutputName, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(OutputName))[0], "ogr")

# Or you can give it any name using the line below
# iface.addVectorLayer(OutputName, "anyName", "ogr")
```

---

Note:

1. This will only work if you **uncheck** the `Open output file after running algorithm` option in the script interface.
2. You may have to include the following in your script:

   ```
   import os
   from qgis.utils import iface
   ```